# What are some arguments against democracy that were espoused by philosophers?

Tags: democracy

I am interested in reading controversial opinions about democracy, especially coming from well-educated philosophers. I am not sure if I ever heard of philosophers being fervently against democracy, most philosophers seem to be actually its biggest proponents, so I am curious to know if anyone went against the current on this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democracy:_The_God_That_Failed - Hans Hermann Hoppe studied under https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%BCrgen_Habermas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Thoreau

The argument (if I get it right) is in *Civil Disobedience*

And it's gist is: In a *community* if I am a bad member its results are manifest. 
Whereas in a (large enough) *country* no such effects are palpable.

And so, the vote once in 4-5 years is a soul degrading "free lunch" since there is no commitment from my side and I can ask/demand anything.

Aside: My gpa used to say: What kind if system do you expect when those who would rule start as beggars for votes?

Speaking of philosophers against democracy surely you've heard of...?

## Plato

Answer (score 1):

Aristotle’s definition of Democracy can’t be more controversial:

> In our original discussion about governments we divided them into
>   three true forms: kingly rule, aristocracy, and constitutional
>   government, and three corresponding perversions- tyranny, oligarchy,
>   and democracy. Of kingly rule and of aristocracy, we have already
>   spoken, for the inquiry into the perfect state is the same thing with
>   the discussion of the two forms thus named, since both imply a
>   principle of virtue provided with external means. We have already
>   determined in what aristocracy and kingly rule differ from one
>   another, and when the latter should be established. In what follows we
>   have to describe the so-called constitutional government, which bears
>   the common name of all constitutions, and the other forms, tyranny,
>   oligarchy, and democracy.
>
> It is obvious which of the three perversions is the worst, and which
>   is the next in badness. That which is the perversion of the first and
>   most divine is necessarily the worst. And just as a royal rule, if not
>   a mere name, must exist by virtue of some great personal superiority
>   in the king, so tyranny, which is the worst of governments, is
>   necessarily the farthest removed from a well-constituted form;
>   oligarchy is little better, for it is a long way from aristocracy, and
>   democracy is the most tolerable of the three.

He considers democracy as a perversion of constitutional government, also known as Politeia.

Although  everything needs to be read in context 
http://classics.mit.edu/Aristotle/politics.4.four.html